# WriteableBitmapEx error in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

hi im trying to use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) in windows phone but the code is not working...what am i doing wrong in this?

```
        double height = image1.ActualHeight;
        double width = image1.ActualWidth;
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Tulips.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        BitmapImage newImg = image1.Source as BitmapImage;

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {

                int grayScale = (int)((image1.writeableBmp.GetPixel(j, i).R * 0.3) + (image1.writeableBmp.GetPixel(j, i).G * 0.59) + (image1.GetPixel(j, i).B * 0.11));
                Color nc = Color.FromArgb (grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
                newImg.SetPixel(j, i, nc);

            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'not working'? An exception is thrown, nothing happens, the result isn't what you expected?

Comment: What kind of error are you experiencing? Is `grayScale[0]` just a typo here on SO?

Comment: BTW, `Color.FromArgb()` takes four arguments, first argument representing the `Alpha` channel.

Comment: @KooKiz errors int the second for loop..code cannot be complied

Comment: @AndersGustafsson yes that was a typo...still the second for loop is not working

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to modify a `BitmapImage` (`newImg`). You have to create a `WriteableBitmap`:

```
var newImg = new WriteableBitmap(image1.Source);
```

to be able to modify the bitmap image afterwards.

Then (if you are referencing *WriteableBitmapEx*) you should be able to get the pixel value in the `grayScale` expression directly from `newImg`:

```
byte grayScale = Convert.ToByte((newImg.GetPixel(j, i).R * 0.3) + 
    (newImg.GetPixel(j, i).G * 0.59) + (newImg.GetPixel(j, i).B * 0.11));
```

And then there is also `Color.FromArgb` statement that should look more like this:

```
Color nc = Color.FromArgb (255, grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);
```

Comment: it says invalid arguments in `var newImg = new WriteableBitmap(image1.Source);` and `Color nc = Color.FromArgb (255, grayScale, grayScale, grayScale);`

Comment: it says cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte'

Comment: That's right, arguments in `FromArgb` should be of type `byte`. Instead of making a cast in the `grayScale` computation use `byte grayScale = Convert.ToByte(...)`. I'll modify above...

Comment: Regarding error in construction, do you have the code lines in correct order above? Maybe `newImg` should be initialized from `img`?

Comment: for `var newImg = new WriteableBitmap(image1.Source);`it says cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'

Comment: Try to cast `image1.Source` to `BitmapSource`.